# Change field values using Elasticsearch Painless

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I want to check the length of each field under the object `alert`.

If it's longer than X, change it to `value was truncated since it was too long`

```
"_source" : {
          "random" : 123455,
          },
          "@timestamp" : "2021-10-15T21:55:12.938+0000",
          "application" : "app",
          "alert" : {
            "app_key" : "XYZ",
            "host" : "Hostname",
            "check" : "CPU overloaded",
            "status" : "ok"
          },
```

For some reason, I get this error when trying to apply my script:

```
    "type" : "script_exception",
    "reason" : "runtime error",
    "script_stack" : [
      "java.base/java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextNode(HashMap.java:1584)",
      "java.base/java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:1617)",
      "java.base/java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:1615)",
      "for (alert in ctx._source.alert.entrySet())\n      {\n      ",
      "                               ^---- HERE"
    ],
    "script" : " ...",
    "lang" : "painless",
    "position" : {
      "offset" : 38,
      "start" : 7,
      "end" : 65
    },
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "concurrent_modification_exception",
      "reason" : null
```

Script:

```
{
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless",
    "source": """
      for (alert in ctx._source.alert.entrySet())
      {
      if (alert.getValue().length() > params.number_of_characters) {
        ctx._source.alert[alert] = "value was truncated since it was too long"
      }
      }
    """,
    "params": {
      "number_of_characters": 5
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot modify the map directly while iterating over the set returned by entrySet, only through the `setValue` method of the entry.

Per the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#entrySet()) for `entrySet()`:

> Returns a Set view of the mappings contained in this map. The set is
> backed by the map, so changes to the map are reflected in the set, and
> vice-versa. If the map is modified while an iteration over the set is
> in progress (except through the iterator's own remove operation, or
> through the setValue operation on a map entry returned by the
> iterator) the results of the iteration are undefined. The set supports
> element removal, which removes the corresponding mapping from the map,
> via the Iterator.remove, Set.remove, removeAll, retainAll and clear
> operations. It does not support the add or addAll operations.

Try with the following script:

```
for (alert in ctx._source.alert.entrySet()){
    if (alert.getValue().length() > params.number_of_characters) {
        alert.setValue("value was truncated")      
    }      
}
```

Comment: Great ! It worked !

Thank you, thank you, thank you ! <3

Answer (score 1):

Eventually, with the help of Nicolas, I used this:

```sh
PUT _ingest/pipeline/rawpayload-ingest/
{
  "processors": [
    {
      "script": {
        "description": "Loop through all fields in alert object and shorten them if needed",
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": """
          for (field in ctx.alert.entrySet()) {
            if (field.getValue() instanceof String) {
              if (field.getValue().length() > params.number_of_characters) {
              field.setValue(field.getValue().substring(0, params.number_of_characters) + "...truncated")
              }   
            }
          }
        """,
        "params": {
          "number_of_characters": 512
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```